# The final output is supposed to be within [ ] and the + = is supposed to be in middle

Tags: c++

The output for sum part should be detailed. But I don't know to to do it.

```
int main()
    {
    cout << "This program is to find the sum of two Different arrays";
    cout << endl;

    // variable declaration
    int Sizer = 0, Sizec = 0, first[10][10], second[10][10], sum[10][10];
    cout << "Enter the number of rows for array: ";

    // input
    cin >> Sizer;
    cout << "Enter the number of columns for an array: ";
    cin >> Sizec;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the elements of first Array";
    cout << endl;

    // nested loop execution and input
    for (int c = 0; c < Sizer; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            cout << "Enter elements of array [" << c + 1 << "]" << "[" << d + 1 << "]: ";
            cin >> first[c][d];
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the elements of second Array";
    cout << endl;

    // nested loop and execution
    for (int c = 0; c < Sizer; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            cout << "Enter elements of array [" << c + 1 << "]" << "[" << d + 1 << "]: ";
            cin >> second[c][d];
        }
    }

    // outputting a sum
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sum of Arrays: ";
    cout << endl;

    // loop execution and sum
    for (int c = 0; c < Sizer; c++)
    {
        cout << "[";

        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            cout << first[c][d];

            if (d != Sizec - 1)
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "]";

        if ( Sizer== Sizer / 2)
        {
            cout << "+";
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "   ";
        }

        cout << "[";
        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            cout << second[c][d];
            if (d != Sizec - 1)
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "]   ";
        // output sum
        cout << "[";
        for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
        {
            sum[c][d] = first[c][d] + second[c][d];
            cout << sum[c][d];
            if (d != Sizec - 1)
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "]";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I need the some to be as shown. Can anyone help me with the code.

```
  [2 3 5]   [2 5 0]   [4 8 5]
  [1 2 3] + [4 8 1] = [5 10 4]
  [1 4 2]   [4 1 2]   [5 5 4]
```

I just corrected it. But i do not know how to represent it in above form
so know can you help me out with it
I have added some lines. so this is my new code and i fix some parts and only have problems with adding the + and = sign and i know it has to do something with no of rows or size of rows

Comment: The expected result is at the end of output.And my apologies for all the mistakes

Comment: First fix the errors in your and make the test code which means if some copies it it shall compile.... And please indent your code.

Comment: Second: What exactly is your problem? You can output a single matrix so where is the problem to output three of them?

Comment: Don't try to print the matrices one by one (it's possible but much harder), instead print *whole lines*.

Comment: @user6556709 i did fix the code. sorry for all of that. and thanks for the repluy. but it isnt giving me the required output

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude which is harder. Becuz i didnt understand by which you meant is harder. One by one or whole lines. I know i ask a lot of unneccesary question

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pen. Write down the first full line of the output you want. If you can do that, then you can do that in a program as well.

Comment: @ZackRaez You didn't fix the code (includes missing, using namespace missing, first line "," -> ";" and you didn't correct the indentation.). You should really draw it first on a squared paper and look what should go where.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i tried but its giving me an ouput like                           thisSum of Arrays:
[2+4]=:[6][2+4]=:[6][2+55]=:[57]
[2+6]=:[8][2+6]=:[8][2+5]=:[7]
[2+4]=:[6][2+5]=:[7][3+5]=:[8]  becuz of the loop.

Comment: Try to print the line `"[2 3 5]   [2 5 0]   [4 8 5]"`. Then try to print the line `"[1 2 3]   [4 8 1]   [5 10 4]"`. Then try to print the line `"[1 4 2]   [4 1 2]   [5 5 4]"`. Don't bother with anything else for the moment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not trying to ask personal question but can i know when you started programming at what age and how many years are you programming for. and for the reply im will try to do what you say

Comment: I wrote my first program (a simple "hello world" type program in BASIC on a Commodore VIC20) before I was ten. I bought my own first "real" computer (an Amiga 500) in 1989, in my mid-teens, and started programming in C within a year of that. Been programming non-stop (just about :)) since that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i tried this but i got this output:      Sum of Arrays:
[2][2]=[4][3][3]=[6][4][4]=[8]
[5][5]=[10][6][6]=[12][7][7]=[14]
[8][8]=[16][9][9]=[18][0][0]=[0]                                                                                            this is the code for (c = 0; c < Sizer; c++) {

   for (d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
   {
    sum[c][d] = first[c][d] + second[c][d];
    cout << "[" << first[c][d] << "]";
    cout << "[" << second[c][d] << "]";
    cout <<"="<< "[" << sum[c][d] << "]";
   }
   cout << endl;

Answer (score 2):

You may adjust the output order and use [std::setw()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_setw.htm) to organize the output.

1. **Adjust the output order.** Try to write down what you want **line by line** and that is how `cout` works. In your example, the first output should be

```
[2 3 5]   [2 5 0]   [4 8 5]
```

instead of

```
  [2 3 5]
  [1 2 3]
  [1 4 2]
```

By acting this way, the output order shouldbe

```
1: [a[0][0] a[0][1] a[0][2]]   [b[0][0] b[0][1] b[0][2]]   [c[0][0] c[0][1] c[0][2]]
```

To make it clear, the output code should be

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Sizer; i++)
    {
        // output first matrix
        cout << "[";
        for (int j = 0; j < Sizec; j++)
            cout << first[i][j] << " ";
        cout << "]\t";
        // output the second
        cout << "[";
        for (int j = 0; j < Sizec; j++)
            cout << second[i][j] << " ";
        cout << "]\t";
        // output sum
        cout << "[";
        for (int j = 0; j < Sizec; j++)
            cout << sum[i][j] << " ";
        cout << "]\n";
    }
```

Add the code above to the end of your code, and we could get outputs below

```
[1 2 3 ]        [1 1 1 ]        [2 3 4 ]
[4 5 6 ]        [1 1 1 ]        [5 6 7 ]
[7 8 9 ]        [1 1 1 ]        [8 9 10 ]
```

You may want to do a calculation to decide when to `cout` the `+` and `=`.

2. **Use setw() to align your output.** As we can see, number `10` occupies more space than number < 10, and also you may also get an output like this

```
[1 2 3 ]        [1 1 1 ]        [2 3 4 ]
[4 50 6 ]    +    [1 1 1 ]    =    [5 6 7 ]
[7 8000 9 ]        [1 1 1 ]        [8 9 10 ]
```

To avoid this, we could preset some space for each number, for example, add a `setw(4)` before `cout` a number

```
cout << setw(4) << first[i][j];
```

would get output below

```
[   1   2 232]  [ 1002301  21]  [ 1012303 253]
[  12   1   1]  [   2 343   1]  [  14 344   2]
[   1   1   1]  [   2   3   1]  [   3   4   2]
```

This may be useful to you.

Comment: thanks but they didnt teach me setw so i cant use it. and for the output     [2 3 5] 2 is the first element of first array . so when using the loop im confused of how to make them appear in same line

Comment: i tried this but i got this output:      Sum of Arrays:
[2][2]=[4][3][3]=[6][4][4]=[8]
[5][5]=[10][6][6]=[12][7][7]=[14]
[8][8]=[16][9][9]=[18][0][0]=[0]                                                                                            this is the code for (c = 0; c < Sizer; c++) {

   for (d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
   {
    sum[c][d] = first[c][d] + second[c][d];
    cout << "[" << first[c][d] << "]";
    cout << "[" << second[c][d] << "]";
    cout <<"="<< "[" << sum[c][d] << "]";
   }
   cout << endl;

Comment: Sure you'll get such wrong output since your current output order is a[0][0]b[0][0]c[0][0], a[0][1]..... Please try to write down the output you want and you'll find out the order should be a[0][0]a[0][1]a[0][2]  as shown in the answer above.

Comment: this is the code but my output is wrong can you plz explain:                        for (c = 0; c < Sizer; c++) 
  {
   cout << "[";

   for (d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
    cout << first[c][d] << " ";
   cout << "]\t";
   cout << "[";
   for (int d = 0; d < Sizec;d++)
    cout << second[c][d] << " ";
   cout << "]\t";
   // output sum
   cout << "[";
   for (int d = 0; d < Sizec; d++)
    sum[c][d]=first[c][d]+second[c][d];
    cout << sum[c][d] << " ";
   cout << "]\n";
   cout << endl;
  }
 }

Comment: this is the output                   Sum of Arrays:
[4 5 6 ]        [4 5 6 ]        [-858993460 ]

[7 8 9 ]        [7 8 9 ]        [-858993460 ]

[0 2 3 ]        [0 6 5 ]        [-858993460 ]

Comment: Well this is due to your missing `{}` of `for` loop. Without `{`and`}`, the `for` statement will only effect the exact following sentence, which is `sum[c][d]=first[c][d]+second[c][d];` in your code. Therefore when `for` statement is done, the variable `d` is added up to 3, and following code is `cout<<sum[c][d]` equaling to `cout<<sum[c][4]`. But the variable sum[c][4] do not have a value, and is set default by -858993460 so you've got **one** strange negative output.

Comment: It is uncomfortable to read codes without formatting. If you still have questions, feel free to email me at `troppingz@gmail.com`. Please paste your code with formatting and right indents next time maybe in email:)

Comment: thanks you really help me out. I will contact you. Thanks again

Comment: can i now how long you have been coding

Comment: sorry for nit contacting you through email. I had a bug where i couldn't message you so i came here.Thanks to you i have fixed the code. but now i'm just having problems with the adding the + = between the []: something like this                   
[1 1 1]   [0 0 0]   [1 1 1]
[1 1 1] + [0 0 0] = [1 1 1]
[2 2 2]   [1 1 1]   [3 3 3] like shown in the question
   some one told me to divide the number of rows by two and add this two in between. like in middle. sorry if now im just being annoying. Thanks for all the help anyways.

Comment: can anyone please provide with a link to learn multi dimensional arrays or the concept behind it. I have visited some websites but none helped me by much

Comment: 1. I wrote my first code before 10 and the first useful code using Pascal when I was 12.

Comment: 3. Try to imitate the computer to output **line by line**. If you must write the output down line by line then when would you write the `+` and `=`? Hints: you may want them to be in the middle line of the output. But define `middle` by yourself.

Comment: To make it clear, when writing line by line, you have to watch out `is this the middle line?` So this is what the program should do -- if (this is the middle line) cout<<+; And 2 is your `middle` of 3, 2.5 is your `middle` of 4, 3 is your `middle` of 5(when you output 5 lines, `+`should be in the 3rd line), find the pattern and fill the expression of `if`

Comment: i did update the code and can you help me with the + = and sign.